# Determining hot and neutral on old unmarked wires

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, old-house

This house dates back to 1900, give or take 10 years in either direction. The previous fixture was removed when I was not present, and perhaps I should not trust how the last fixture was wired anyway. Here's how it looks now:
[image: previous ceiling moulding hole]
When I first examined the hole in the ceiling, about 1 inch of either wire was sticking through the center hole in this fixture, held on to the plaster above by two screws (not three) and a copious amount of paint and plaster. There were little shreds of cloth insulating material on one of the wires. The rest of the wire was bunched up behind the fixture, held in place by the plaster.[image: are the wires even supposed to go through the hole in the middle?]

How can I tell which wire is hot and which is neutral? Once I've established that, what should I do with the grounding wire on the fixture? I have this "voltage testing device" available to me but will buy something else if necessary. [image: Sperry voltage tester ET6102] For safety, is it enough to wrap each wire in electrical tape (and not jam them through that tiny hole in the fixture) or should I clip the bits with burnt insulation and add a small length of wire if there isn't enough play in the new fixture's wires?

Finally,(Bonus question!) what the heck is that threaded rod ? It's not centered in the moulding but it looks like a handy place to mount the new fixture, as I'm not keen on going into the plaster alone as was done before.

Comment: "For safety"… I'd be looking at replacing *all* that old wiring. Bonus: on a century-old house, that threaded pipe could have been gas. I've still some left in my own ceiling that I've never bothered fully removing. Mine are all capped, but so long as the entire gas run was disconnected a lifetime ago, it's not really important - it's not like anyone is ever going to try reactivate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll let the electricians address your questions in the morning re your old wiring and mounting of a new fixture. The tool you need is called a non-contact voltage tester, found in the electrical dept. of your hardware store. Cost is $8 to 25. They resemble a fat pen. You turn it on and bring it near --but not touching --one of the wires. The tool will light up and/or beep if the wire is hot. Do the same thing for the other wire(s).